# Visual Studio Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I was trying to find out what the current version of typescript is in my VS2015 U3 installation.

When executing tsc -v in my VS command prompt I get 2.0.6

When looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript I see version 1.8

When I create a new project the csproj file contains

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

So what version is installed and how can I use the version 2.0.6 in Visual Studio?

I have a project form Github that contains

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

When I try to build I get the error "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.
Does this relate to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-installing the latest version of typescript from the website:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

We have had similar issues. Make sure Update 3 is installed, as it silently breaks the installer if not: Goto about in visual studio and on the left should read Version XXXX Update 3).

You can also check the installed version of typescript in about, scroll down the installed products and you should see it.